# Two arrays equality test

Tags: javascript, arrays, equality, p5.js

This is more of a logic question. 
I can't figure out what is wrong with my function

```
// This function is meant to check if 3 pixels 
// are colored and therefore if the canvas is full

function checkIfFull() {
    let emptyPixel = [0, 0, 0, 0];
    let pixel1 = get(1, 1);
    //let pixel2 = get(599,599);
    //let pixel3 = get(400, 50);
    console.log(pixel1);

    if (pixel1 === emptyPixel) {
        console.log(true);
    } else {
        console.log(false);
    }
}
```

I am running the P5.js library. The get() is giving me an Array [a, b, c, d] 
and I am trying to test for equality or differences between those two (emptyPixel / pixel1)

These are the things I have tried:  Testing every position within the arrays.

Thanks!

Comment: Arrays are not compared using == operator, you should loop through the array and compare each element. In any other language like java, there are utilities that help find the equality.

Comment: Did that : used a for loop and tested the equality for each element.
Got the same result : no Ideia why :/

Comment: could you post the code that you use for that?

Comment: You might want to try it out as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853974/3830432

Comment: Another possibility when checking "equality" of arrays is to convert them to strings (via `JSON.stringify()`) and then compare, though this might not be optimal in all situations. In the case you illustrate, that could work nicely, though I can't speak to the performance implications.  Food for thought, that's all.

Comment: @Zeus
Used something like that : 

// This function is meant to check if 3 pixels 
// are colored and therefore if the canvas is full

function checkIfFull() {
    let emptyPixel = [0, 0, 0, 0];
    let pixel1 = get(1, 1);
    //let pixel2 = get(599,599);
    //let pixel3 = get(400, 50);
    console.log(pixel1);

for (let i = 0; i > 3; i++) {
    if (pixel1[i] === emptyPixel[i]) {
        console.log(true);
    } else {
        console.log(false);
    }
}
}

Comment: I am not sure that this is really a duplicate of "how to compare arrays" The key phrase in this question is, " This function is meant to check if 3 pixels are colored and therefore if the canvas is full" Can you elaborate on what you mean by, "canvas is full"?

Comment: I am using the p5.js library which allows me to create a canvas (display window); 
the end goal of this program is to make a digital painting. 
So the script draws into the canvas and I am looking for a way to trigger an event when most of the pixels of the canvas have gained colores ( the canvas starts white) 
My ideia is to check for three pixels scared throughout the canvas.
hope this is understandable :)

Answer (score 0):

If an empty pixel is an array [0,0,0,0] you can test it with something like this

```
function checkIfEmpty(pixel) {
  return pixel.every(x => x === 0)
}
```

Comment: A pixel with value [0,0,0,0] could be set to black and an alpha value of zero. I don't think we can determine if a pixel has been set our not by just checking the color and alpha values.

Answer (score -1):

Your array can be simply transformed to string to check equality

```js
const emptyPixel = "0,0,0,0";

function checkIfFull() {
    
    const pixel1 = get(1, 1);

    return pixel1.toString() === emptyPixel
}

console.log(checkIfFull)
```

Comment: Why can we assume that a pixel with value [0,0,0,0] is empty? Why is a function that checks for equality with something called, "emptyPixel" called checkIfFull? I am not trying to be difficult and would really like to help your improve this answer.